# How to get textwrap in Python to break on underscores or arbitrary characters (not just hyphens and whitespace)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, word-wrap

The following works well:

```
from textwrap import fill
print(fill("hello-there", 8))
```

Outputs:

```
hello-
there
```

However, I am using a lot of text where words are separated with **underscores, not hyphens**. The option `break_on_hyphens` is great but there seems to be no way to specify other separators.

I looked around and was really surprised to not find anything on this. Does anyone have any idea of the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

here's a modified version that supports justify values (left, right, middle, justified) and fixes a bug in Francois Bertrand's code:

```py
def text_justify(text, width):
    words = text.split()
    if len(words) < 2:
        return text.ljust(width)
    if len(text) < width * 0.75:
        return text.ljust(width)
    spaces_needed = width - sum(len(word) for word in words)
    spaces_between_words = spaces_needed // (len(words) - 1)
    extra_spaces = spaces_needed % (len(words) - 1)
    justified_words = []
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):
        word = words[i]
        spaces_to_add = spaces_between_words + (1 if i < extra_spaces else 0)
        justified_words.append(word + ' ' * spaces_to_add)
    justified_words.append(words[-1])
    return ''.join(justified_words)


def text_wrapper(source_text, width, separator_chars=[" "], justify="left"):
    output = ""
    if type(source_text) != list:
        source_text = [source_text]

    if justify == "left":
        source_text = [s.rstrip() for s in source_text]
    if justify in ["middle", "justified"]:
        source_text = [s.strip() for s in source_text]
    if justify == "right":
        source_text = [s.lstrip() for s in source_text]

    for line in source_text:
        current_length = 0
        latest_separator = -1
        current_chunk_start = 0
        char_index = 0
        while char_index < len(line):
            if line[char_index] in separator_chars:
                latest_separator = char_index
            output += line[char_index]
            current_length += 1
            if current_length == width:
                if latest_separator > current_chunk_start and line[char_index + 1] not in [c for c in separator_chars if c == " "]:
                    cutting_length = char_index - latest_separator
                    if cutting_length:
                        output = output[:-cutting_length]
                    output += "\n"
                    current_chunk_start = latest_separator + 1
                    char_index = current_chunk_start
                else:
                    output += "\n"
                    current_chunk_start = char_index + 1
                    latest_separator = current_chunk_start - 1
                    char_index += 1
                if line[char_index] in " ":
                    char_index += 1
                current_length = 0
            else:
                char_index += 1
        output += "\n"

    output = [o.rstrip().rstrip("\n") for o in output.rstrip("\n").split("\n")]

    if justify == "middle":
        output = [f"{' ' * math.ceil((width - len(o)) / 2)}{o}" for o in output]
        output = [o.rstrip() for o in output]
    if justify == "right":
        output = [o.rjust(width) for o in output]
    if justify == "justified":
        output = [text_justify(o, width) for o in output]
        output = [o.rstrip() for o in output]
    return output
```

This function supports both string and a list of strings as input. Each string will be wrapped separately and it returns a list of strings as the lines. If you want it to return a a printable single string replace `return output` to `return "\n".join(outpt)`.

Francois Bertrand's `wrap_custom`:

```
In [274]: wrap_custom("lorem ipsum dolor", [" "], 11, False).split("\n")
Out[274]: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor']
```

(this is wrong because "lorem ipsum" can fit in 11 characters)

my `text_wrapper`:

```
In [276]: text_wrapper("lorem ipsum dolor", 11, [" "])
Out[276]: ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor']
```

Comment: Hah! Thanks for the correction, I'll check out!

Answer (score 0):

So the quick-and-dirty way I found was to simply write a wrapper around the function that replaces the desired character with a hyphen to make that function work. It's not very Pythonic, but would get the job done. I'm hoping someone else can come up with the "actual" answer (if it exists...).

Note that I wrote a "fill" version as I am looking for a string, not a list.

Python 3:

```
from textwrap import wrap

def fill_custom_sep(source_text, separator_char, width=70, **kwargs):
    chunk_start_index = 0
    replaced_with_hyphens = source_text.replace(separator_char, '-')
    returned = ""
    for chunk in wrap(replaced_with_hyphens, width, **kwargs):
        if len(returned):
            returned += '\n' # Todo: Modifiable
        chunk_length = len(chunk)
        if chunk[-1] == "-" and source_text[chunk_start_index + (chunk_length - 1)] == separator_char:
            chunk = chunk[:-1] + separator_char
        returned += chunk
        chunk_start_index += chunk_length
    return returned

print(fill_custom_sep("hello_there", "_", 8))
```

Outputs:

```
hello_
there
```

Answer (score 0):

While we're at it, here is a simple function to wrap around a list of separators (not just one):

```
from textwrap import wrap

def wrap_custom(source_text, separator_chars, width=70, keep_separators=True):
    current_length = 0
    latest_separator = -1
    current_chunk_start = 0
    output = ""
    char_index = 0
    while char_index < len(source_text):
        if source_text[char_index] in separator_chars:
            latest_separator = char_index
        output += source_text[char_index]
        current_length += 1
        if current_length == width:
            if latest_separator >= current_chunk_start:
                # Valid earlier separator, cut there
                cutting_length = char_index - latest_separator
                if not keep_separators:
                    cutting_length += 1
                if cutting_length:
                    output = output[:-cutting_length]
                output += "\n"
                current_chunk_start = latest_separator + 1
                char_index = current_chunk_start
            else:
                # No separator found, hard cut
                output += "\n"
                current_chunk_start = char_index + 1
                latest_separator = current_chunk_start - 1
                char_index += 1
            current_length = 0
        else:
            char_index += 1
    return output

wrapped = wrap_custom("Split This-This_Text", [" ","_","-"], 7, False)
```